# Geolocation not working in Cordova Android emulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using visual studio Cordova tool for creating application. I am uding geolocation of HTML5 for getting user location.

When I execute it in ripple naxus-galaxy, it working fine, but when I run it in android emulator, it's not working at all. It shows me GPS system on top bar. but after that nothing is happening. I have also added geoLocation plugin.

My code is,

```
    // For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.

        var geo_options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 50000,
            timeout: 30000
        };

        var mapWatchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, geo_options);
        alert("Watch" + mapWatchId);
    };


    function onSuccess(position) {
        alert("onSuccess = " + JSON.stringify(position));
    };

    function onError(error) {
        alert("Error");
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert("Please share your location with us to move ahead.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert("Location information is not available, Check your internet connection.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert("We are not able to fetch your location details.");
                break;
        }
    };
    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
})();
```

My config file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.Geo" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>Geo</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

Even, it is not calling gMap() function at all, because alert itself is not coming.

Please check above code and tell me necessary changes.

Thank you.

Comment: You are using the "body.onload" event instead of "deviceready". What the body has loaded, it has nothing to do with the cordova api was loaded.

Comment: Test in real device it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test geolocation mode inside android emulator, same goes to push notification. You need to test in in real mobile device.

Comment: It's strange that this is a problem, because the google maps works perfectly fine based on the location that you can set in the emulator config area :/